# How to calculate values at textchanged event?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have tried at textchanged event

```
decimal a1 = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00);
decimal b1 = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00);
decimal c1 = Convert.ToDecimal(0.00);
a1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Advance.Text.Trim().ToString());
b1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal.Text.Trim().ToString());
c1 = b1 - a1;
txt_Net.Text = c1.ToString();
```

This works only one time when I again changing value. It gives error of incorrect format at txt_Advance.text

Comment: On which line exactly? Can you please debug your code and tell the value of `txt_Advance.text`? Also what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: CurrentCulture! is what?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The value of txt_Advance.text  comes from datagridview.also want to calculate at textchange event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `TryParse` method. Actually what is happening is that when you `enter` some value it is being parsed correctly. But when you press `backspace` that value is removed and `textbox` becomes `empty` so trying to convert an `empty string into decimal` gives `format exception`.

Either you can use `TryParse` method or you can check that if `textbox` value is `not empty` than `convert` it to `decimal` value.

```
decimal.TryParse(txt_Advance.Text.Trim().ToString(),out a1);
```

OR

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt_Advance.Text.Trim().ToString()))
  a1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Advance.Text.Trim().ToString());
```

Comment: Error: can't implicitly convert bool to decimal

Comment: you would have written `a1=decimal.TryParse(txt_Advance.Text.Trim().ToString(),out a1);` so no need to assign value in this case only write `decimal.TryParse(txt_Advance.Text.Trim().ToString(),out a1);` this will assign value to `a1`.

Comment: It again giving error when emptied

Comment: You have two texboxes you need to do for both also when adding these two do same there as well.

Comment: Also update your question with updated code.

Comment: Yes I have applied at both textboxes

Comment: Also you are subtracting the two values so when is an empty string other is decimal so this will also give error.